# Scrapy Crawler Doesn't Follow Links

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am having some trouble trying to figure out why my secondary function is failing to follow through to the new link and then output data. the `parse` function works just fine. It's when it calls back to `parse_puppy` that nothing happens. When I check the json output I see that everything from `puppy` was successfully scraped, but there's nothing from `parse_puppy`.

On line 28, if I change the method to `follow` I get results, but it's the same result about dozen times.

Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.cmdline import execute

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "puppyDetails"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://ws.petango.com/webservices/adoptablesearch/wsAdoptableAnimals.aspx?species=Dog&gender=A&agegroup=UnderYear&location=&site=&onhold=A&orderby=name&colnum=3&css=http://ws.petango.com/WebServices/adoptablesearch/css/styles.css&authkey=io53xfw8b0k2ocet3yb83666507n2168taf513lkxrqe681kf8&recAmount=&detailsInPopup=No&featuredPet=Include&stageID=&wmode=opaque']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # GRAB ALL TOPICAL PUPPY DETAILS
        for animal in response.css("div.list-animal-info-block"):
            yield {
                'puppy_name': animal.css('div.list-animal-name a::text').get(),
                'puppy_id': animal.css('div.list-animal-id::text').get(),
                'puppy_sex': animal.css('div.list-animal-sexSN::text').get(),
                'puppy_breed': animal.css('div.list-animal-breed::text').get(),
                'puppy_age': animal.css('div.list-animal-age::text').get(),
                'puppy_link': animal.css('div.list-animal-name a::attr(href)').get()
            }

            # DIVE INTO DETAILS PAGE
            detail_page = response.css('div.list-animal-name a::attr(href)').get()
            self.logger.info('get puppy details')
            # GO TO THE PUPPY DETAILS
            yield response.follow_all(detail_page, callback=self.parse_puppy)

    def parse_puppy(self, response):
        # GRAB PUPPY DETAILS
        for puppyDetails in response.xpath('//*[@class="detail-table"]//tr'):
            yield {
                'puppy_id': puppyDetails.xpath('//*[@id="lblID"]/text()').extract(),
                'puppy_status': puppyDetails.xpath('//*[@id="lblStage"]/text()').extract(),
                'puppy_intake_date': puppyDetails.xpath('//*[@id="lblIntakeDate"]/text()').extract()
            }

execute(['scrapy','crawl','puppyDetails'])
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'generator' in <GET https://ws.petango.com/webservices/adoptablesearch/wsAdoptableAnimals.aspx?species=Dog&gender=A&agegroup=UnderYear&location=&site=&onhold=A&orderby=name&colnum=3&css=http://ws.petango.com/WebServices/adoptablesearch/css/styles.css&authkey=io53xfw8b0k2ocet3yb83666507n2168taf513lkxrqe681kf8&recAmount=&detailsInPopup=No&featuredPet=Include&stageID=&wmode=opaque>
```

Answer (score 1):

The line should be

```
yield from response.follow_all(detail_page, callback=self.parse_puppy)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I've updated that line and I've gotten rid of the error, but I'm still not getting results from the next page. I tried a couple of things as I noticed that I was getting a 404 when performing the GET on ```detail_page```. I concatenated the result from ```puppy_link``` with the domain and directory and I updated the second function so to log a message if it's called, which it's not. Any ideas?